# Java, How can I use .nextLine as an object reference

Tags: java

I want to use something I scanned as a reference to an object for a method in a different class. Basically scanner.nextLine().method(); but I get cannot find symbol no matter what do I try

I am scanning a txt file and want to make a new class Word for each new word, and if the word is repeated I am supposed to increase a counter with a method from class Word.

```
    class Word{
int counter = 1;

public counterIncrease(){
counter ++;
}
}
```

Im supposed to scan for words, put them in an ArrayList named here fileArray and then check if they repeat, if they do I should increase the counter from class Word, if not I make a new Word

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
String temp = scanner.nextLine();
   if(fileArray.contains(temp){
       temp.counterIncrease();
   else{
        fileArray.add(new Word(temp);
       }
```

Comment: If i correctly understand your problem then you want to read the line in a custom object reference. It will return a string. Later you can construct any object using that

Comment: @K K posting some more code might help everyone.

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you're trying to do. `scanner.nextLine()` will return a string reference, and you can call any string method on it. What do you mean by "as a reference to an object for a method"? A short but complete example of what you're trying to achieve would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: I just added some code, basically I want to use something I scanned for a method without typing it manually

Comment: @K K `fileArray.contains(scanner.nextLine())` will get the scanner to skip the next line so you may want to store the value if you're going to access it later on in the line `scanner.nextLine().increaseCounter();`

Comment: I've added an answer, but next time please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - it doesn't help that we don't know what `fileArray` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least three problems here. Firstly, if your `fileArray` is a `List<Word>`, you're trying to find a string (the return type of `nextLine()`) within a list of `Word` objects... that's never going to work.

Secondly, you're trying to call `counterIncrease()` on a string rather than on an instance of `Word`.

Thirdly, you're calling `nextLine()` multiple times when I'm pretty sure you only want to call it once.

I strongly suspect you want a `Map<String, Word>` at which point you can use:

```
String line;
while ((line = scanner.nextLine()) != null) {
    Word word = map.get(line);
    if (word === null) {
        map.put(line, new Word(line)); // I assume this constructor exists
    } else {
        word.counterIncrease();
    }
}
```

This code only calls `nextLine()` once per iteration, looks up the current word *by string*, and only calls `counterIncrease()` on an instance of `Word`.

I would personally change the `Word` code so that `counter` is 0 until you call `counterIncrease`, at which point the loop would become:

```
String line;
while ((line = scanner.nextLine()) != null) {
    Word word = map.get(line);
    if (word === null) {
        word = new Word(line);
        map.put(line, word);
    }
    word.counterIncrease();
}
```

In other words, you're separating "make sure we've got a `Word` instance" from "increase the count for the word". It's not a huge difference, admittedly...

It's not clear whether your `Word` class *actually* has the necessary constructor - it should look something like this:

```
public final class Word {
    private int count;
    private final String text;

    public Word(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public int incrementCount() {
        return ++count;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Having said all this, if you *just* want the word counts, you don't need the `Word` class at all. You can just use a `Map<String, Integer>` or `Map<String, AtomicInteger>`. For example:

```
Map<String, AtomicInteger> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

String line;
while ((line = scanner.nextLine()) != null) {
    AtomicInteger counter = map.get(line);
    if (counter === null) {
        counter = new AtomicInteger();
        map.put(line, counter);
    } 
    counter.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are completely right that I want to use nextLine(); once.

I have not learned about map yet, is there any other way?

How can I convert a string into an instance of Word?

Comment: @KK: Well you need a `Word(String)` constructor. I assumed you'd got one of those but hadn't shown it. Do you?

Comment: @KK: You *could* do this just with a list, but it would be somewhat odd to do so. I suggest you learn about maps.

Comment: Yes I do

It's basically public Word(String text){this.text = text} with 

private String text; 

in Word class

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also wonder how you would go about finding the word that has the biggest counter

Comment: Do you think using AtomicInteger is a little bit overkill? I don't see the need for thread-safe increments in this context.

Comment: @JamesS: I'm not using it for the thread safety aspect - I'm using it effectively as a mutable version of `Integer`.

Comment: @KK: That's a different question. I'd probably copy the `Word` references into a list and then sort that using a comparator which compares by count.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
   // you only want to use nexLine() once per while loop, otherwise your scanner goes forward each time
   String line = scanner.nextLine();
   if(fileArray.contains(line){
      //line.increaseCounter(); there is not such a method for String
   else{
        fileArray.add(new Word(line);
       }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the type problem - how is `fileArray` going to contain `line` when you're adding `Word` instances to it? And just commenting out the call to `increaseCounter` doesn't solve the problem of *wanting* to increase the counter for repeated lines.